# Making an appliction so it is the only application that can connect to my WebAPI

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

How is it possible to create an `Application` to interact with my `WebAPI`. The app will send some info to my website(`WebAPI`) , and then I will update my database with this info, but the problem is how to secure it, so only my app that can interact with my website?

the application designed to be deployed to many computers. and the users can use the application anonymously. for an example [the lightshot app](http://prnt.sc/)

Comment: is the app deployed on one computer, or many? you could have your app send login credentials, or allow access based on IP address. or use a digital certificate. but i'm not sure how you could actually *know* the requests are coming from your app specifically. after all, if an app can be used by a computer, it can be read by a human, and the protocols used by your app can be spoofed.

Comment: well yeah, I know that if the User got the client , I have no control over it, but I wanna secure it, so it's not that easy to `revers engineer / spoof my app`

Comment: I suspect it will be *a lot* easier to authenticate/authorize the *user* then the *application*.  Standards such as OAuth already do an excellent job of that.

Comment: well the application will post data to my website anonymously, that's the problem!

Comment: well, you could obfuscate your code, but that's only going to slow people a little bit, not stop them. you can't encrypt your app, because then the host machine won't be able to use it. about the only thing i can think of is using something like a serial key (which the user can find out no matter where you bury it in the app), and then on your server looking for anomalies in requests and weeding them out. thing is, even by sending a serial key, you are identifying your users, so it's not actually anonymous at all.

Comment: @MixedCoder: Then why does any authorization need to take place at all?  Before going down this rabbit hole, consider the nature of the problem being solved.  You have an application which allows unknown users to post information to your server, and you want to prevent unknown users from posting information to your server?

Comment: @David : I want to authenticate only my app , am trying to find a way to secure my application info , check http://prnt.sc/ for an example . how they are checking wither the `img link` being sent by the application is valid?

Comment: that site allows anonymous upload of images from the website. i'd say the app does the image upload via the same API the website does. and i'd say if an end user copied the source of the website, they could build an app using the same method to upload an image themselves.

Comment: @MixedCoder: They probably have some definition of what is "valid" or "invalid".  I'm not familiar with their code or their functionality, so I wouldn't know what that definition is.  The point is, you seem to be heading down the wrong path entirely.  Asking how to proceed down that path is alien to us, because the path itself doesn't make much sense.  Why do you want *only your app* to connect to your server?  What are you trying to prevent?  If the server is doing its job properly, why should it matter where requests come from?

Comment: @MixedCoder, I'd concur with others here; print.sc for example are unlikely to be trying to validate whether their app or webpage is the one sending the image. There'd be no point as the website allows anonymous upload so would be very simple to replicate in another app. I'd be far, far more worried about policing what's uploaded for illegal images than where the images came from.

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit access to a web site (or any IP port) to just one app.

Validate requests on server and possibly only allow access for authenticated users - that should be enough for most cases (except payed games).

You can make it harder to replay/re-create communication protocol:

- require client certificate for HTTPS to connect
- frequently change code for client and protocol itself
- only allow authenticated users
- rate-limit requests from same user to make it harder to revere engineer the protocol...